# Any ideas on how to remove an ES7 decorator?

Tags: javascript, decorator, ecmascript-2016

I have a few development decorators, like `@timer`, `@checkOptimizations`, etc.  I'm trying to figure out how to remove them in production.  Example class:

```
class Foo {
  @timer
  bar() {
  }
}
```

Now I can make them not *function* pretty easily by replacing the decorator with a no-op function.  But the generated code is pretty heavy (that basic class is 1640 bytes uncompressed vs 353 without the decorator).

Comment: Implement a plugin for a transpiler you use so that it removed the node before translating it.

Comment: @zerkms -- Okay, any ideas on valid syntax to flag a decorator as dead code?  I'd prefer to not invent something :)

Comment: Make it your plugin parameter so that all `@timer`s were removed. Otherwise I cannot think of something that is not as terrible as an explicit comment right before a decorator, eg: `// dead code decorator` ;-D

Comment: Btw, you could have a `@dead(['timer'])` - a parameterized decorator that accepts an array with decorators that must be removed during translating.

Comment: @zyklus: Decorate the decorator function with an `@dead` flag?

Answer (score 0):

I've built a plugin to solve this problem. It removes **all** the decorators before transpiling the code. We use it when we want to Unit Test our code since we don't want the decorator applied to the "unit" in test (i.e. class).

Here it is: 
https://github.com/vladpalos/babel-plugin-remove-decorators

If you want to remove only certain decorators, you might want to use this one:
https://github.com/elierotenberg/babel-plugin-strip-decorator